# What is the traditional name of this Lisp function?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I've seen this function elsewhere, and as I recall, it's got a standard name. I can't remember it though, and perusing Alexandria's `list.lisp` library didn't reveal any secrets to me.

```
(defun familiar-function (list func)
  (loop for e in list
        collect (if (listp e)
                    (familiar-function e func)
                    (funcall func e))))
```

Comment: A recursive `mapcar`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like [`tree-map`](https://common-lisp.net/project/docudown/documentation/metabang.utilities-package/function-tree--map.html), also called [`maptree`](http://www.informatimago.com/develop/lisp/doc/com.informatimago.common-lisp.cesarum.list.html#MAPTREE):

```
(familiar-function '(() (3 2 3) (2) (2) (55 22 33))
                   #'1+)
=> (NIL (4 3 4) (3) (3) (56 23 34))
```

As mentioned in the comment, your approach assume trees are proper lists and do not apply the function to non-nil `cdr` cells, contrary to the linked functions.

Comment: I usually name **tree-map**  as **maptree** in Common Lisp, in similarity with other **mapxxx** functions.  However, do note that this still treats cons cells as lists, not as arbitrary trees (e.g.,the function is never called with the cdr of a cons), so this differs from some tree mapping functions.  The documentation that you linked to would make me think that **tree-map** would call fn on the car and the cdr.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor This is true, I could not find a function that would fit exactly the code provided. The name tree-map is mostly found in Scheme exercises.

Comment: I do assume the datapoints are proper lists. That is precisely as intended.

Comment: @PaulNathan I understand, but that's closest I could find. I don't know if there is a different name for your function.

Comment: @Paul yes, the function that you've provided works just fine with lists, but the traditional maptree function would descend by car and cdr. E.g., mapping 1+ over ((1 . 2) . 3) would produce ((2 . 3) . 4) but would fail on (1 2) [which is (1 . (2 . Nil))] because nil isn't a number.

Comment: @Paul, see, for instance, the discussion in https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/comp.lang.lisp/Puq_kiQ1cFk.